# Wordpress - Exclude post types from selected categories before publishing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

I have the following snippet to stop my users from publishing posts without choosing some taxonomy before published, and i have post types called "slides" without any categories, and i can't publish or update the slider posts without any tax, so i need to exclude this post type from the snippet below or exclude the admin.

```html
function force_post_categ_init() 
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
function force_post_categ() 
{
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
  echo "
  jQuery('#publish').click(function() 
  {
    var cats = jQuery('[id^=\"taxonomy\"]')
      .find('.selectit')
      .find('input');
    category_selected=false;
    for (counter=0; counter<cats.length; counter++) 
    {
        if (cats.get(counter).checked==true) 
        {
            category_selected=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(category_selected==false) 
    {
      alert('You have not selected any category for the post. Please select post category.');
      setTimeout(\"jQuery('#ajax-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');\", 100);
      jQuery('[id^=\"taxonomy\"]').find('.tabs-panel').css('background', '#ffe59d');
      setTimeout(\"jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');\", 100);
      return false;
    }
  });
  ";
   echo "</script>\n";
}
add_action('admin_init', 'force_post_categ_init');
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'force_post_categ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by adding if current user can manage_options after the next function.
`if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {//do something}`
good luck!